# Spring integration imap - multiple email accounts from the same domain

Tags: spring, imap, spring-integration

I'm using spring's imap mechanism in order to recieve emails from my account into my server.

this works like a charm.

Anyhow, a new requirmemnt came up - instead of listening to a single email account i will have to listen on a multiple number of accounts.

Iv'e tried creating a new channel for each of these account.  it WORKS!

problem is that each channel i added meaning a new thread running.
since i'm talking about a large number of accounts it is quiet an issue.

My question is:

Since all the email accounts (I would like to listen to) are in the same domain i.e:
acount1@myDomain.com
acount2@myDomain.com
acount3@myDomain.com
....

Is it possible to create a single channel with multiple accounts?

Is there any alternative for me than defining N new channels?

thanks.
Nir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean channel adapter, not channel (multiple channel adapters can send messages to the same channel).

No, you can't use a single connection for multiple accounts.

This is a limitation of the underlying internet mail protocols.

If you are using imap idle adapters, yes, this will not scale well because it needs a thread for each. However, if you are only talking about a few 10s of accounts, this is probably not an issue. For a much larger number of accounts, it may be better to use a polled adapter.

But, even so, unless it's a fixed number of accounts, the configuration could be burdensome (but you could programmatically spin up new adapters).

For complex scenarios like this, you may want to consider writing your own "adapter" that uses the JavaMail API directly and manages the connections in a more sophisticated way (but you still need a separate connection for each account). It wouldn't have to be a "real" adapter, just a POJO that interracts with JavaMail. Then, when you receive a message from one of the accounts, send it to a channel using a `<gateway/>`.

Comment: can you give me example code for separate connection for each account

Comment: Just add a separate inbound adapter for each account; they can send to the same channel.

Comment: i want to dynamically add inbound adapter , is that possible?

Comment: Yes; it easiest when using the Java DSL - see [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/27/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-candidate-1-is-available) and the [dynamic-tcp-client sample](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client).